# Improper formatting with fillRect

Tags: java, swing, rectangles

I want to make a background for a game I have created.
I'm having some issues with fillRect.
Does getHeight and getWidth have to be in a certain order or should getX/Y/Height/Width be used at all?

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //Graphical loop start
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,1440,900) ;
    g.fillRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    //Graphical loop end
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: yes .`fillRect(x,y,width,height);` if you mix then you will get different rectangle

Comment: Of course width and height have to be in a certain order. That's how function parameters work. The order is specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you are using the Graphics object instead of Graphics2D. You need to set the paint colour first then use the fill method.

```
g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight));
```

Rectangle2D constructor arguments are: x-coordinate of top-left, y-coordinate of top-left, width, height

It is good practice to use the `Graphics2D.fill()` method which will accept any object that implements the `Shape` interface. This makes it easier to change a shape to a different one should you decide to do so.

Comment: Since the op hasn't made a copy of the Graphics context, then it won't matter which instance they use, they are both the same thing. The op could simply use setColor to achieve the same result. Though I tend to prefer using the Shape API